# Me da un error al ejecutar python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django

Hola estoy siguiendo un curso de Django en youtube y al intentar usar el comando:

> python manage.py migrate

me sale el siguiente error:

```
File "manage.py", line 17
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

El 20 primeras líneas del código de manage.py es el siguiente:

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Proyecto1.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Estoy programando en vs code utilizando python 2.7.16 y la versión 3.1.3 de Django.

Comment: Información insuficiente. Publica las 20 primeras lineas de "manage.py"

Answer (score 1):

La versión de Python que estás usando (2.7) no soporta la sintaxis `raise Exception() from other_exception`.

Te recomendaría cambiar a Python3, pues además python 2.7 ya se considera obsoleto y no recibirá más actualizaciones.

Si por cualquier razón te ves obligado/a a seguir usando 2.7, puedes "emular" el `raise ... from` instalando el paquete `future` y usando:

```
from future.utils import raise_from

def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Proyecto1.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise_from(ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ), exc)
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```